# MySQL Update Sorted Number

Tags: mysql

I have MYSQL data like this

```
id  | number
1   | 3
4   | 4
7   | 7
10  | 5
11  | 6
```

I have the database like that, and how to update the `number` so it will be sorted incremental?
Which mean the result will be like this

```
id  | number
1   | 1
4   | 2
7   | 3
10  | 4
11  | 5
```

---

i updated the question so there will be no confusion in `id` and since id will be not consecutive

Comment: Does the `number` field also contain unique values, or can there exist the same `number` twice?

Comment: yes the `number` field can contains exist value (NOT UNIQUE) before sorted. The number field type is VARCHAR without UNIQUE KEY or any KEY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set @val = 0;
update  table_name set number = (@val:=@val+1);
```

This would work even if table is:

```
id  | number
1   | 3
4   | 4
7   | NULL
10  | 5
11  | NULL
```

to be like this:

```
id  | number
1   | 1
4   | 2
7   | 3
10  | 4
11  | 5
```

Comment: What if there are gaps in `number` (i.e. number doesn't exist) ?

Comment: like this?

    1   | 1 
    4   | 2 
    7   | 3 
    10  | NULL 
    11  | 5

Comment: It will set all of the number column to be 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ... even if some of them are NULL

Comment: you also can add order by to be sure !
`update  table_name set number = (@val:=@val+1) order by id asc;`

Comment: This work like charm, but i wonder if i have 10.000 row database and will be added more. Will be this database query running longer?

Comment: @GusDeCooL I hope to correctly understand what you mean! so i should say:

It will work but it's not needed to renumber your primary key every day. But the way to run this query faster in the second time that you want to do this, is to renumber the primary key from the maximum of primary key you had last time. I mean you should renumber from `id==10,000` to the last column that is created recently in your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table set number=id where 1
```

Comment: no no, sorry. the ID might be not be sorted. since some of it will be deleted.

Comment: so please change your table structure in your question to its worst state

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET @idrank = 0;
SET @numrank = 0;

UPDATE 
    tbl a
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, @idrank:=@idrank+1 AS id_rank
        FROM tbl
        ORDER BY id
    ) b ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT number, @numrank:=@numrank+1 AS number_rank
        FROM tbl
        ORDER BY number
    ) c ON b.id_rank = c.number_rank
SET
    a.number = c.number;
```

This will account for gaps and irregularities in the `number` field as well as duplicates. Say the entire data set was something like:

```
id   |   number
---------------
2    |   534
3    |   421
6    |   2038
7    |   41
10   |   5383
11   |   5
12   |   933
15   |   43
```

The resulting table set after the update will be:

```
id   |   number
---------------
2    |   5
3    |   41
6    |   43
7    |   421
10   |   534
11   |   933
12   |   2038
15   |   5383
```

### **Explanation:**

It basically takes the ascending ranks of each field separately and joins on the ranks so that the ordered `id` is matched up with corresponding ordered `number`.

The first `INNER JOIN` subselect will look like this:

```
id   |   id_rank
---------------
2    |   1
3    |   2
6    |   3
7    |   4
10   |   5
11   |   6
12   |   7
15   |   8
```

Then the second `INNER JOIN` subselect will like this:

```
number   |   number_rank
---------------
534      |   5
421      |   4
2038     |   7
41       |   2
5383     |   8
5        |   1
933      |   6
43       |   3
```

Then when you join the two subselects on `id_rank` = `number_rank`, you line the ascending order of the two fields up. Once you have that, updating becomes a simple matter of setting the table's number = the second joined table's number.